# How to search from Json in laravel

Tags: json, laravel, eloquent

I have a json valued table and need to search  value from it how I can decode json so I can search through it. I am trying to implement like query but doesn't work for me.

```
id     country            company_name                    Main_category   
71       33          {"en":"hitech","ar":"hitech"}            14,22,24
```

Code:

```
$matchThese = [ 'country' => $request->input('country'),
                        'company_name' => $request->input('company_name'),
                        'main_category' => $request->input('main-category'),
                      ];

        $comma_separated = $request->input('company_name');

        $companies = Company::where(function($q) use($comma_separated) {
            $q->where('main_category', 'like', '%,' . $comma_separated . ',%');
            $q->orWhere('main_category', 'like', $comma_separated . ',%');
            $q->orWhere('main_category', 'like', '%,' . $comma_separated);
        })
        ->where($matchThese)->orWhere($matchThese)
        ->orWhere('main_category', 'like', $comma_separated . ',%')->paginate('3');
```

If I search on `hitech` it shows nothing because main_category part is in `JSON` formate

Comment: You haven't got condition on `company_name` at all

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the company_name you should change your query for this.

```
$companies = Company::where('company_name', 'like',  '%'.$comma_separated.'%'.);
```

you were comparing main_category with company_name. You also shouldn't need as many where clauses. Since you are looking for a simple pattern in a json string, the way the commas are positioned shouldn't matter.